# Having trouble installing separating ceiling fan and light switch

Tags: electrical

I am a major novice and recently widowed, trying to do something my husband has always done, please be kind!  I was trying to install a double switch to separate out the light from the ceiling fan.  There are two cables coming in from the top of the box that I assume are ceiling fan and light, but there is a third coming in from the bottom of the box that I have no idea where it goes to, though I know the breaker is connected to the living room outlets and lights.  Please see photo of how it was originally wired. I have attempted to wire the mystery cable to each of the upper sets, and then to the double light plate, and both times the breaker blew.  I'm okay forgoing separate switches at this point, but fearful of whether it's safe to wire it like the original (two black wires only, with the neutral and ground only connected to each other).  The instructions on the Leviton "Decora Two Switches" are lacking to say the least...  The breaker is a 15A and I am using a 15A light switch. [image]

Comment: One cable will be power from the panel.  The question then becomes if that cable goes on to somewhere else or the two blacks goes to the fan/light.  If the two blacks go to the fan light it is easy.  You just separate the two blacks to different switches.  Join the single power to two wires to each switch.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look as if you have the wiring in place to have seperate switches for the fan and the light.

The cables in the box are bringing in power, transfering power to the fan, and taking power out to other devices, ( switches and/or outlets.)

There is hope.  You can purchase a fan control that will mount in the box, replacing the switch.  [Wall mount fan control](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Ceiling-Fan-Wall-Switch-9050H/202801200?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D27-027_020_CEILING_FANS-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-CEILING_FANS_New&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D27-027_020_CEILING_FANS-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-CEILING_FANS_New-71700000113498907--&gclid=CjwKCAjwgZCoBhBnEiwAz35Rwogx7pswDuF-JRLK8HNGiqOt_XtMwJQ0Ng8r2KdvFctrjisN5xFmzRoCFuwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) There are different styles and types to choose from. ( google wall mount fan controls)

This will require the receiver to be mounted in the fan. ( instructions are included with the new unit). The wires to the wall control will need to be connected per instructions and the switch discarded.

Of course the power to the circuit should be shut off at the breaker.

If you are not comfortable with this job, you should call an electrician. They have done these plenty of times.

Comment: Thank you so much! My living room has one of these installed and I love it!  I do have an electrician whose done some work for us, I think I might just call him for this :)